# How do I to identify forced pushes in Git?

Tags: git, push, blame

By looking into my team's commit log, I found lines of code changes from same patch appear twice in different commits.

Further prove is like this: Master branch has commit A in its change list(as being seen in "git log").
If I check out commit A as HEAD, I can find commit B in its change list.
However if I checkout master as HEAD, I can *not* find commit B in its change list.

I believe there was a non-fast-forward push happened at some point. But is there any easy way to identify such non-fast-forward push by using git command or other tools?

Comment: try to see the conflicts and see what was going on using: `git log -p -c -1 <SHA-1>`

Comment: By "non-fast-foward" do you mean `git push --force`?

Comment: @Schwern yes to your question.

Comment: Most likely they applied the same changes in two separate branches. Git does not record changes, it records snapshots, which means that if the two identical changes were done on the same branch, the second one wouldn't exist. It has to be two separate branches. So may not have been forced push.

Comment: If one of those two commits are the ancestor of the other, there **has** to be a commit in between that changes that section of the code back.

Comment: To answer your question, the only way to figure out if someone force pushed to your remote repository is to look at the logs of your repository hosting service, or to analyze the reflog on the remote. The history of the repository does not have any clues at all that would identify a force push, unless someone explicitly stated something in the commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Github (and possibly others), a forced push on a pull request will be visible in the PR history, though I'm not sure how long they record it.

Using the [Github v4 API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) forced pushes *should* be available on a [PullRequest's](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/pullrequest/) timeline as a [BaseRefForcePushedEvent](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/baserefforcepushedevent/) and/or [HeadRefForcePushedEvents](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/headrefforcepushedevent/).

---

You ***may*** be able to detect a forced push if you have access to the bare remote repository, but it's a complicated. I'll illustrate below.

Normally pushes are building on top of existing commits. If you had a local repo a few commits ahead of your remote like so...

```
origin

A - B - C [master]

local

A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          D - E [master]
```

And you `git push` D and E will be send up and the local and remote will have the same history for `master`.

```
origin

A - B - C - D - E [master]

local

A - B - C - D - E [master][origin/master]
```

But if `local` does some rebasing, let's say they rewrite B, history has "diverged".

```
origin

A - B - C - D - E [master]

local

A - B - C - D - E [origin/master]
 \
  B1 - C1 - D1 - E1 [master]
```

Now if you try to push it will be rejected, `git push` will not merge for you it will only fast-forward. This is typically solved with a `git push --force` which simply replaces the existing history.

```
origin

A - B - C - D - E
 \
  B1 - C1 - D1 - E1 [master]

local

A - B - C - D - E
 \
  B1 - C1 - D1 - E1 [origin/master][master]
```

Note that the old commits are still there, both in your local and origin. And they will remain there until garbage collection happens, normally for weeks.

On local you can see old commits with [`git-reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). The remote repository *may* have a reflog, and if it is you're in luck. But it may not. Yet the old commits are still there.

You can see them in the `objects` directory. Commit 53715b45364b160ce6e36d934be903459aebe254 is in the file `objects/53/715b45364b160ce6e36d934be903459aebe254`... though it may be [packed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) for efficiency.

So the commit is likely still there, but how can you find evidence of rebasing? One trick is to run [garbage collection](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) and see what's left. `git gc` will only pack referenced commits, and it will save unreferenced commits younger than two weeks old (this can be configured with the various "prune" config options). Any commits left in `objects` are likely to be old commits.

```
$ find objects -type f
objects/3b/d1f0e29744a1f32b08d5650e62e2e62afb177c
objects/5f/941d2600a72d0126689ee1d51225cb7d3c0a05
objects/33/f273a8ea4378453f297dc9a69e81a374534361
objects/02/5f398bbc061f1fa0b61f8454f5d134f43a8a4c
objects/d7/3afbb06ed2245a0c82ab147ea28eabeb41196e
objects/b4/036885119a0c0a726d4a07c39880f5d4e5d688
objects/7d/311b920e2b6ba8ac14198c1a30fe41af8e34fe
objects/42/e2ac33f56ca2b7f51c87db4baeb66980525c40
objects/19/6803e246079172e91973f583672290988e89c9
objects/81/7b794bceb50878e569b18a336e52181c3bf45c
objects/86/e041dad66a19b9518b83b78865015f62662f75
objects/9a/095aeaea32de8059face7ff2ccea63a2337dbb
objects/09/1dddfa09138dc26cbf0dec4603a4aa95001d1c
objects/53/715b45364b160ce6e36d934be903459aebe254
objects/0a/f001a378ba6af70af76c10466b90c8f96e8403
objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
objects/84/d0a65b5b8b4d9376f08e3c4518057b16ee6082
objects/25/7cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99
```

The old commits are `53715b45364b160ce6e36d934be903459aebe254`, `b4036885119a0c0a726d4a07c39880f5d4e5d688`, and `025f398bbc061f1fa0b61f8454f5d134f43a8a4c`. After running `git gc`...

```
$ git gc
Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Building bitmaps: 100% (5/5), done.
Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Computing commit graph generation numbers: 100% (5/5), done.

$ find objects -type f
objects/02/5f398bbc061f1fa0b61f8454f5d134f43a8a4c
objects/b4/036885119a0c0a726d4a07c39880f5d4e5d688
objects/pack/pack-57c98c590b41d20da1b6892ce4a18ab735272583.pack
objects/pack/pack-57c98c590b41d20da1b6892ce4a18ab735272583.bitmap
objects/pack/pack-57c98c590b41d20da1b6892ce4a18ab735272583.idx
objects/info/commit-graph
objects/info/packs
objects/53/715b45364b160ce6e36d934be903459aebe254
```

The unreferenced commits were left unpacked.

I don't know how foolproof this technique is, but it makes it possible to find evidence of a recent force push.

---

The best option to solve this problem is to not have it in the first place.

If you disallow direct commits to `master`, requiring all commits to be done via PR, this ensures you have a record of everything that goes into `master`, that all additions to `master` are done with clean merges, and that nobody (except admins) can change master's history. In concert with automated checks and tests this ensures `master` is always in good shape and the team has a solid base to work from.

In addition, forced push after rebase is normal, but a normal `git push --force` remains dangerous. Instead use `git push --force-with-lease` to push after rebase. This will check that only the commits which were changed by rebasing are force pushed. `git push --force-with-lease` makes rebasing safer. I have it aliased to `git repush`.

Comment: Does PR refer to pull request? How can I check it in GitHub server?

Comment: @MingD. Yes, PR = Pull Request. I just added instructions to the top.

Comment: I updated my question body. Can you read it again to see if an instance of using --force can be confirmed here?

Comment: @MingD. It may have simply been a bad merge. Can you provide us with `git log --graph --decorate --oneline master` showing the history and connections around the duplicate commits? Be sure to sanitize your commit messages.

Comment: I can try to capture an abstract graph without commit messages. But that will wait for sometime next week.

Comment: Note that your own Git has a reflog for `origin/master`, so if you regularly do `git fetch` operations (so that your `origin/master` keeps, say, an hourly record of the remote's `master`), you can browse this and identify any time at which the reflog records a change that is not a fast-forward. It won't tell you *who* did the force-push, though.

Comment: So basically there is no straightforward way to achieve that.

Comment: @MingD. Pretty much. The nature of Git and a forced push makes it very difficult to detect, very similar to recovering a deleted file. The best way to achieve it is to have a process that disallows force pushing to critical branches.